# PhantomJS : Unable to Perform onClick Activity

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

My objective is to extract the page content from popups. Previously i was just performing dynamic scraping using PhantomJS and it works on majority of the websites but there were few websites which are using AngularJS for popups.
In that case dynamic scraping is not working and all of them have ng-click in pop tags.

I am first trying to find out ng-click labels then after performing some filtration i got the tags that contains ng-label.
i used that tag and ng-click value to find element using css selector , which is the best choice for me , as i need to automate this on a wide scale.

My code is working fine with firefox but not working with phantomjs.It is unable to find the css path

```
def __init__(self):
    # self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=cap)
    # self.driver.implicitly_wait(90)
    # self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(90)
    # self.driver.set_script_timeout(90)
    self.driver.set_window_size(1120, 1000)

def get_data(self,link):
    soup = None
    tag_list = []
    try:
        self.driver.get(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.driver.page_source)
        elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[(@ng-click)]")

        for element in elements:                
            attr_value  = element.get_attribute("ng-click")
            tag_name =  element.tag_name
            tags = soup.find_all(tag_name,{'ng-click':attr_value})
            for tag in tags:
                try:
                    tag_text = str(tag)
                    if "login" in (tag.text).lower() or "log in" in (tag.text).lower() or "signin" in (tag.text).lower() or "sign in" in (tag.text).lower():
                    # if "log in" in tag_text.lower() or "login" in tag_text.lower():
                        comp_class_ = element.get_attribute('class')
                        class_ = comp_class_.replace(" ",".")
                        css_path = str(tag_name+"."+class_)
                        element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, css_path)))  
                        element.click()
                        # self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(css_path).click()
                        tag_list.append(tag)
                except Exception as e:
                    pass
        print (self.driver.page_source).encode('utf-8')
    except Exception as e:
        print "Error while Scrapping {}".format(link)
    return soup
```

Comment: if it's not throwing any exception, you can try clicking using javascript.

Comment: For me python is the best option